# MongoDB: Error: quota exceeded on single document mongoimport

Tags: json, mongodb

I generated a single document that contains meta data about another collection. It is a 7.3mb JSON file. I attempted to import it to mongoDB through the MongoLab service using the command:

```
>mongoimport -h dsPORT.mongolab.com:PORT -d pstat -c meta -u ME -p MYPASSWD --file /Users/ME/pstat/data/metaComb.json
```

And got the error:

```
2015-08-13T09:34:13.733-0500 error: quota exceeded
2015-08-13T09:34:13.736-0500 tried to import 1 objects
encountered at least 1 error(s)
```

I've run this file through parsers to confirm the JSON formatting. That seems to be why most people encounter mongoimport errors. So I'm fairly certain the JSON is valid, and the 7.3mb file does not exceed mongo's 16mb limit.

Anyone have an idea on where this error is coming from or possible workarounds? I'm researching GridFS right now, seems like that may work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at /etc/mongodb.conf : find string "quota = true" and switch to "false" or just comment it.
Then restart mongodb.